# How to init alias array with another one in golang?

Tags: arrays, go

```
type Foo [3]int

arr := [3]int {1, 2, 3}
foo := &Foo{arr}
```

It doesn't work in golang, it says:

> Cannot use 'arr' (type [3]int) as type int

how should I do it correct & elegantly ;-), I want my code can be write as below:

```golang
func_name(&Foo{arr}) // func_name is to receive a *Foo and do something
```

If I write my code like this:

```golang
type Foo struct {array [3]int}  
  
arr := [3]int {1, 2, 3}  
func_name(&Foo(arr))
```

It works fine, but I wish my code can be as more simple as possible.

Comment: What does "elegantly" mean? Do you want to initialize a `Foo` directly, or do you just want a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)?

Comment: You do not have a type alias, `Foo` is a distinct type. You can use initialize a `Foo` in a literal if you want, or you can convert it and assign it. The result of a type conversion is not addressable.

Comment: Seeking the Platonic ideal of The Simplest code is not what StackOverflow is for. [What problem](https://xyproblem.info/) are you trying to solve with this aliasing, specifically?

Comment: Is `Foo(arr)` not simple enough? What kind of solution are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
arr := [3]int{1, 2, 3}
foo := Foo(arr)
```

Here's a [playground link to try it](https://play.golang.org/p/h2BZzRwXEBc). This isn't an *alias* though; arrays will be copied when assigned. If you're looking for aliasing, consider using slices instead.

---

Your original code creates a new `Foo` and attempts to initialize its first element with `arr`, which fails for the reason the compiler specifies.

Comment: I have re-edit my question, I want to get the reference directly, thanks for you help~ ;-)

Comment: @JhinKoo: I don't understand what changed in your question, and whether my answer applies or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "aliasing" you mean "two different types refer to the same underlying buffer": take a pointer to an array, and cast it to a pointer of another type.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo [1]int

func main() {
    bar := [1]int{}
    foo := (*Foo)(&bar)

    bar[0] = 0xdeadbeef
    fmt.Println(*foo)
}
```

Which is neither elegant nor idiomatic in Go — that's what slices are for.